# with Azure SDK installed, no more publish to file system option

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

Now that I have installed Azure SDK and published some of my sites to Azure, I no longer have a build option permitting publish to local filesystem. How can I get said feature back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have VS2012 installed, but... when right-clicking your cloud project, you should see both a Publish... option and a Package... option. Choosing the latter will write the package + configuration file to disk, with either local or cloud settings.

[image: Choose Package...]

[image: Select configuration]

[image: Files generated and stored on disk]

Comment: My menu options are different in VS2010, so I'll have to dig a little more to get at the package option - but thanks to your guidance I'll find what I need now.